# Invert or XOR a line in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I can draw a solid-color line easily in Qt, but now I need to draw a line by inverting the original pixels, or perhaps XOR-ing the QBrush.

I'm asking for the equivalent of `SetROP2(R2_NOT)` or `SetROP2(R2_XORPEN)` in Win32.

Is that possible using Qt? I want to do it so I can easily "unpaint" it later.

Comment: What is the inverted color of Rgb(10, 10, 10)? Please clarify.

Comment: Well, when mentioned alongside XOR-ing, it's flipping every bit (bitwise inversion, or the ~ operator in C).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
QPainter dc(widget);

dc.setCompositionMode(QPainter::RasterOp_SourceXorDestination);
dc.setPen(QColor(0xff, 0xff, 0xff));

dc.drawEllipse(center, r1, r2);
```

Other composition modes are described [in the QPainter documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#composition-modes). To undo individual graphics operations, this one should be exactly what you want, though -- just set the same pen you used in the first place and redraw the shape.